# Extract the second occurrence of the string in SAS

Tags: sas, find, substr

I have the following text with the currency and amount fields.

The transaction currency is USD and the amount is 200.00 The transaction currency is EUR and the amount is 150.00

I need to create four variables `tran1`, `amt1`, `tran2` and `amt2` variables

```
Tran1 amt1 Tran2 amt2
USD    200  EUR   150
```

I used `substr` and `find` functions but it is taking the first occurrence only.

```
 Tran1=substr(string,find(string,”transacrioncurrency”)+21,3);

 Amt1=substr(string,find(string,”the  amount is”)+12,5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the second occurrence start after the position of the fisrt one :

```
data f;
p="The transaction currency is USD and the amount is 200.00 The transaction currency is EUR and the amount is 150.00";
p1=find(p,"The transaction currency",1);
Tran1=substr(p,p1+28,3);
p2=find(p,"the amount is",1);
 Amt1=substr(p,p2+14,6);

 p3=find(p,"The transaction currency",p1+1);
Tran2=substr(p,p3+28,3);
p4=find(p,"the amount is",p2+1);
 Amt2=substr(p,p4+14,6);
;

run;
```

result :

```
p                 p1    Tran1   p2  Amt1    p3  Tran2   p4  Amt2
The transacti..     1   USD     37  200.00  58  EUR     94  150.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach using `input` statements that you can use if your text is in an external file:

```
data example;
input @'is '  tran1 $3. @;
input @'is '  amt1 :8. @;
input @'is '  tran2 $3. @;
input @'is '  amt2 8.;
datalines;
The transaction currency is USD and the amount is 200.00 The transaction currency is EUR and the amount is 150.00
;
run;
```